# What does the phrase (int const * const b) mean in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, syntax, arguments

A have a function that takes in "int const * const data" as one of its arguments, and I have no idea what that means. I was expecting this function to take in an array, so I feel like this is an array, but I have no idea how. The lack of a comma is throwing me off. This is one argument.

EDIT: Ok, I didn't realize const was a keyword. Is there anyway that this points to an array? Because I'm expecting an array.

Comment: `const` has a specific meaning very different from something like `a`.

Comment: Also, [here, have a C declaration -> English translator](http://cdecl.org/).

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, that makes a lot of sense. I've changed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` is a keyword that applies to the argument on the left (or on the right if there's nothing left on the left) and denotes immutability (const-ness).

- `int const*` -- pointer to an immutable (const) int (you can't use this pointer to mutate the int)
- `int const*const` -- immutable pointer to an immutable int

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible that there is an array involved? I'm expecting this function to take in an array.

Comment: There are no genuine array parameters in C. Arrays passed through parameters are translated to pointers to the first element of the array. `int const*const` may well represent an `int` array.

Comment: I see. So how can I access other elements besides the first in the array?

Comment: You can treat the pointer as if it was an array and do array subscripting (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1) on it with: `pointer_to_first[index] == array[index]`.

Answer (score 2):

Two means :

1. The pointer is constant.
2. The data (that the pointer pointing to ) is constant.